# Is a new Android Application instance created for components running in a new process?

Tags: android

If I start a component (say a `Service`) in a new process (using `android:process`), will a new instance of `Application` be created, or the same `Application` will be used across multiple processes?

If one `Application` instance is shared by multiple processes, can I safely call MyApplication.myInstanceMethod()- or do I need some IPC mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will a new instance of Application be created

Yes.

> or the same Application will be used across multiple processes?

No.